# Bind value from service to html - how to observe change by component in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, components

How to bind to the html value from service (the value from service is changing dynamically, but my component doesn't observe it). I just want to show this variable like a text in my component html.

Something like this:

service.js

```
app.service('testService', function() {
    this.testData = {
        test1: 12,
        test2: 13
    }

    this.newFunction() {
        this.testData = {
          test1: 22,
          test2: 23
    }
});
```

component.js

```
(function() {

    angular.module('test.module')
        .component('testComponent', {
            templateUrl: '/test.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm',

            controller: function(testService) {

             this.data = testService.testData;

             this.nextPage = () => {
                 this.newFunction();
             }
         }
    });
```

})();

html

```
<button ng-click="vm.newFunction()">Click</button>
```

So, if I click button, I would like to have data = {test1: 22, test2: 23}, but I still have data = {test1: 12, test2: 13}

How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy):

```
app.service('testService', function() {
    this.testData = {
        test1: 12,
        test2: 13
    }

    this.newFunction = () => {
        var newData = {
          test1: 22,
          test2: 23
        };
        angular.copy(newData, this.testData);
    }
});
```

### The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.service('testService', function() {
    this.testData = {
        test1: 12,
        test2: 13
    }
    this.newFunction = () => {
        var newData = {
          test1: (Math.random()*100).toFixed(0),
          test2: (Math.random()*100).toFixed(0)
        };
        angular.copy(newData, this.testData);
    }
})
.component('testComponent', {
    template: `
      <div>
        <pre>
   test1={{vm.data.test1}}
   test2={{vm.data.test2}}
        </pre>
        <button ng-click="vm.nextPage()">Next Page</button>
      </div>
    `,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: function(testService) {
      this.data = testService.testData;
      this.nextPage = testService.newFunction;
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
    <test-component></test-component>
</body>
```